# connecting to access data base and write to table

Tags: ms-access, excel, database-connection, vba

I have an excel invoice sheet and I want to write the information from the invoice to a table in an Access file. My following code is:

```
Private Sub Button66_Click()
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim connectionString As String

Dim sql As String

connectionString = "DBQ=c:\Users\Public\Public Desktop\InvoiceRecords.mdb; Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"

con.Open connectionString

sql = "insert into Invoices (Customer, Address) values(G6, G7)"

con.Execute sql

MsgBox "Values entered", vbInformation

con.Close

Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

However, when I run it I get a runtime-error '-2147217904 (80040e10)'; Too few parametersentered. 
I'm not what sure what this is. 
Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you're trying to get at the values of cells G6 and G7 in your INSERT query. You need to concatenate them into your insert query instead.

```
sql = "insert into Invoices (Customer, Address) " & _
    "values('" & Range("G6") & "', '" & Range("G7") & "')"
```

Building your sql commands this way makes you vulnerable to SQL injection. A better alternative is to use a parameterized query.

```
Dim cmdInsert As New ADODB.Command
With cmdInsert
    .Prepared = True
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "INSERT INTO Invoices (Customer, Address) VALUES (?, ?)"
    Set .ActiveConnection = con
End With

cmdInsert.Parameters(0).Value = Range("G6").Value
cmdInsert.Parameters(1).Value = Range("G7").Value
cmdInsert.Execute
```

You should also use the Jet driver to connect, instead of the ODBC driver. Use this connection string instead.

```
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data source=c:\Users\Public\Public Desktop\InvoiceRecords.mdb;"
```

Comment: so where in my existing code would I put this? Sorry I'm a little new to this.

Comment: Try changing the sql statement with the one from the first part of my answer - if that works, then the code for the parameterized query would replace the "sql = " and "con.Execute" lines from your code.

Comment: the first part worked, but then I got an error saying operation must use an updateable query

Comment: once I inserted the parameterized query I got the following error: Provider cannot derive parameter information and SetParamerterInfo has not been called

Comment: Try using the Jet driver instead in your connection string.

Comment: do i need to add a reference for that?

Comment: says it c:\Users\Public\Public Desktop\InvoiceRecords.mdb is not a valid path